# Win7 - Extremely long startup unless I wait on login screen

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have noticed the following problem.
When I start up my computer, it loads the login screen normally, then if I enter my password immediately and login, everything is extremely slow for the first 5 minutes. I can't open any software, some other software(riva tuner, skype) I have set up to run on startup take too long to load etc.
If I wait on the login screen for a few minutes instead, before I enter my password and login, everything runs smoothly. Everything opens normally.
Anyone have any idea what might be causing this problem?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this happen in a minimal boot configuration?  Windows allows you to configure what will or will not be started.  Start by starting only the very basics and go from there if the problem does not surface.

Comment: I have tried limiting what starts with the computer but it made no difference. The thing that baffles me is this Wait=Normal Speed, Don't Wait= Extremely Slow

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [start Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7)?

Comment: capture a boot trace of this issue: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140247

Comment: I will try both and get back to you, thanks a lot.

Comment: have you captured the boot trace?